# How do I change World of Warcraft's default font?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is it possible to change Blizzard's font, both size and type, in World of Warcraft? It has to affect both the built-in Combat Scrolling Text and speech bubble. It has to be able to change the font, not one that will replace Blizzard's Combat Scrolling Text.

*The reason I don't want to use an add-on to replace the Combat Scrolling Text is, I like how the built-in combat-text hovers right over the mob's head no matter where it is on my screen. As for the speech bubble, it's just too big of a font.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fontifier](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/fontifier.aspx) seems like it would do what you want. I haven't used it myself though, so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need an addon to do this, and can instead just replace the fonts by naming your chosen fonts equivalently. To make this process a little more convenient, [Fontify](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info14177-Fontify.html) is a batch script which automates the renaming.

Comment: I will check it out. You have a font that you like?

Comment: I don't actually play the game any more, but I'd probably try the [Ubuntu font](http://font.ubuntu.com/) if I did.